# Get sum of two different columns on two different tables linked to a third table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

As mentioned in the title, I would like to have the optimal query to do the following: **WITHOUT SUBQUERIES**

I have this
[image]

So Here, each client has commands(Orders)
each client has factures (bills)
and a bill contains commands(Orders) and the Amount of bills and orders are in MontantCommande and MontantFacture.

So here i need to get the total sum of Orders Commande(MontantCommande) and the total sum of bills Facture(MontantFacture) for each client.

I tried the following but i get wrong result

```
  SELECT cl.idClient
  ,SUM(cm.MontantCommande) AS TotalCommande 
  ,SUM(f.MontantFacture) AS TotalFacture
  FROM client cl
  INNER JOIN commande cm ON cl.idClient = cm.idClientCommande
  INNER JOIN facture f ON cl.idclient = f.idclientFacture
  GROUP BY cl.IdClient
```

How can i do this?

EDIT:
Here the result of my query with select from all concerned tables

[image]

The sum result is wrong here as you can see it must be

1050-1610

680-750

600-1000

**EDIT 2: I ahev to mention that i need to do that without subqueries. Thanks**

Comment: What is the output of your query and what output do you expect?

Comment: Ill Edit The Post to put the result and my expectation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use correlated sub queries like this:

```
SELECT t.idClient,
       (select sum(s.montantcommande) from Commande s
        Where t.idClient = s.idClientCommande) as TotalCommande,
       (select sum(f.montantfactore) from Facture f
        Where t.idClient = f.idClientFacture) as TotalFacture
FROM Client t
```

Or with a join:

```
SELECT commande.idClient,
       commande.sum1 as TotalCommande,
       facture.sum2 as TotalFacture 
FROM
    (SELECT t.idClient,sum(s.montantcommande) as sum1
    FROM Client t INNER JOIN Commande s ON(t.idClient = s.idClientCommande)
    GROUP BY t.id_client) commande
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT t.idClient,sum(s.montantfacuore) as sum2
    FROM Client t INNER JOIN Facture s ON(t.idClient = s.idClientfacture)
    GROUP BY t.id_client) facture
ON(facture.idClient = commande.idClient)
```

Comment: I upvoted your answer  but i made an EDIT that tells i have to avoid using subqueries

Comment: @KarouiHaythem Updated the answer for a sulotion without a subquery

Answer (score 0):

Please use this query

```
SELECT idClient,SUM(MontantCommande) AS TotalCommande ,
SUM(MontantFacture) AS TotalFacture from  client c
Inner join  commande a  on c.IdClient = a.idClientCommande
inner join  facture b on a.IdCommande = b.IdCommandFacture AND a.idClientCommande = b.idclientFacture
group by idClient
```

Answer (score -2):

try this :

```
SELECT cl.idClient, SUM(IIF(ISNULL(cm.MontantCommande),0,cm.MontantCommande)) AS TotalCommande, SUM(IIF(ISNULL(f.MontantFacture),0,f.MontantFacture)) AS TotalFacture
FROM client cl
INNER JOIN commande cm ON cl.idClient = cm.idClientCommande
INNER JOIN facture f ON cl.idclient = f.idclientFacture
GROUP BY cl.IdClient
```

Comment: Thats not good, will result in the same problem he already has because each sum is will be multiplied by the time it appears on the second table

Answer (score -3):

Can you put your Insert statements so i can try it locally ?

Comment: it is a comment not an answer. you can comment on question for further clarification.

Comment: Actauly, he cant , so the correct explanation is: Once you gain enough reputation you will be able to comment on questions for further clarification .. @OAD